# Is there a way to assign a public ip to a pc?

Tags: networking

How do companies like Google Cloud Platform, and AWS dedicate ip's to a VM instance/EC2 instance also, is it possible to do it from home with a pc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask your Internet service provider, they can give you a fixed internet IP address. Maybe you need to pay for it. Then set your PC as input target in your router.